# How to insert custom emojis with SVG format inside a textarea

Tags: javascript, html, emoji

Inserting emojis into a textarea based on their codepoint is possible using the `String.fromCodePoint()` methode.

For example this code is one way to add the smiling face with the codepoint 'U+263A' to a textarea

```js
var textArea = document.getElementById('txtarea');
textArea.value += " " + String.fromCodePoint('0x263A');
```

```html
<textarea id="txtarea">Text value with smiling face</textarea>
```

What if the emojis that are used inside the website are under svg format? Is it possible to append them to a textinput or textarea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `div` with `contenteditable` attribute instead of `textarea`. It's a [plain text control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) so I don't think it would be possible.

```js
var textArea = document.getElementById('textarea');
textArea.innerHTML += " " + String.fromCodePoint('0x263A');
```

```css
#textarea {
  font-family: monospace;
  outline: none;
  background: #efefef;
  border: #888 1px solid;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  font-size: 9pt;
}

img {
  height: 15pt;
}
```

```html
<div id="textarea" contenteditable="true">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a4/Emojione_1F60A.svg" />
</div>
```